# Using parameters from database to change color - Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I'm a giant newb when it comes to coding, so don't cringe. I'd like to use JS to change the color of some text (for a tickertape I'm making) like

```
<div class="example1">
    <h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Tickertekst"></asp:Label></h3>
    <%--<h3><%# Eval("TickerTekst") %></h3>--%>
</div>
```

I'd like to use something along the lines of this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```

But then having "blue" be a color from my database. How would I go on about this?

Comment: Why are you using javascript to set your styles? You should probably be using css for that.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey I would like to make some radiobuttons in order to change colors anytime I want. I can't use queries in CSS, so I got recommended JS to work with.

Comment: What are those parameters from the database? Is that the color that the text should be?

Comment: is it the list of colors that you have in the database?

Comment: @VDWWD Yes. Blue, yellow, purple and the sorts.

Comment: if you pull the value of the color from the DB and you want the color to be render on page load so you can set the tag element with css class/inline style attribute such as: <h3 style="color: <%=dynamic_color_value%>;"></h3>

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden field that keep your colors that its values update by code behind

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="colors" runat="server" value="blue,red" />
```

and code behined:

```
color.Value="blue,red';
```

And get first value for your h1:

```
var colors=$('#colors').val().split(',');
$('h1.title').css('color', colors[0]);
$('h2.title').css('color', colors[1]);
```

And if you do not like using jquery javascript is

```
var colors = document.getElementById('colors').value.split(',');

document.getElementById(ELEMENT_NAME).style.color = colors[0]
```